# StringTemplate: HTML row formatting (odd/even)

Tags: html, stringtemplate

I am new to [StringTemplate](http://www.stringtemplate.org/) template engine and want to use it for generating an html document with a table. I want to alter the style of the table rows depending on whether it is odd or even. I found a discussion   on the stringtemplate-interest mailing list that describes the general approach ([[stringtemplate-interest] Odd even row formatting](http://www.antlr3.org/pipermail/stringtemplate-interest/2008-May/001471.html)).

But I have an additional requirement which breaks this general approach (I think). I want to render rows depending on the existence of a value. So I am working with a conditional expression `$if(expr)$`. My template looks like this.

```
delimiters „$“,“$“
htmlTable(valueA, valueB, valueC, valueD) ::= <<
    <table>
        <tr styleClass='odd'><td>$valueA$</td></tr>
$if(valueB)$
        <tr><td>$valueB$</td></tr>
$endif$
        <tr styleClass='odd'><td>$valueC$</td></tr>
        <tr><td>$valueD$</td></tr>
    </table>
>>
```

In the given template I can not use the hard coded styleClass attribute, because it would render the table wrong if the valueB parameter does not exist.

Is my requirement realizable with a template engine like StringTemplate, which focus on separation of model and view? Or is there too much *model* in the requirement as to implement it in the view? I know how to do it in other template engines (i. e. FreeMarker or Apache Velocity) or I might use some [fancy CSS](https://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/evenodd.en.html) or javascript stuff but I would rather keep the model-view separation and use StringTemplates internal instruments.